# if $f[X]=f[Y]$ then $X=Y$???

Tags: functions, proof-writing, fake-proofs

I'm pretty sure this is false, but this proof I came up with seems to be valid.

Proof.
If $f[X]=f[Y]$, then for any $x\in X$, $f(x)\in f[X]=f[Y]$, now $f(x)\in f[Y]=\{f(x)|x\in Y\}$, so $x\in Y$; hence $X\subseteq Y$. For any $y\in Y$, $f(y)\in f[Y]=f[X]$, so $y\in X$; hence $Y\subseteq X$.

But then this is a counterexample:
let $f(1)=2$, $f(0)=2$, $X=\{1\}$, $Y=\{0\}$, then $f[X]=f[Y]$ but $X\neq Y$.

Where is the mistake in the proof?

Comment: $f(x)\in f[Y]$ does not imply $x\in Y$; it only implies that there exists some $y\in Y$ such that $f(x) = f(y)$.

Comment: In the line $f(x) \in f[Y] = \{ f(x) \mid x \in Y \}$, the two $x$'s are not the same.

Comment: Amplifying prets comment, in $\{f(x)|x\in Y\}$, $x$ is a bound (aka dummy) variable. That means you can replace it with any other letter without changing the meaning. So that set is the same as $\{f(z)|z\in Y\}$. So you can conclude that $f(x)=f(z)$ for some $z\in Y$, but not that $x=z\in Y$.

Comment: As a general rule, if one comes up with a counterexample to a proposed result, and also a proof of the result, one can usually go through the proof step-by-step, seeing exactly which step fails for the counterexample. I think that would have identified the error here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that $f(x)$ belongs to $f[Y]$ does not imply that $x \in Y$. That part does not follow.

Comment: if it was bijective then it'd be true right

Comment: or just injective is enough?

Comment: Yep! Injectivity is sufficient. Do you think you can prove it with that assumption?